# HttpContext.Features vs HttpContext.Items In Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

**What is the differences between these two Properties?**

I can use `HttpContext.Items` instead of `HttpContext.Features` to share data between `middlewares`. The only difference I see is that I tell `Items` for a key and it gives me an object and I have to cast it. This casting can be done in `Features` automatically.

Is there something else behind them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The biggest difference is that the `HttpContext.Items` is designed to store `Key-Value-Pair`, while the `HttpContext.Features` is designed to store `Type-Instance-Pair`.

To be more clear, `HttpContext.Items` is designed to share items  within the scope of current request, while the `HttpContext.Features`, which is an instance of `IFeatureCollection`, is by no means to be used like that .

The `IFeatureCollection` interface represents a collection of HTTP features, such as:

1. `IAuthenticationFeature` which stores original PathBase and original Path.
2. `ISessionFeature` which stores current Session.
3. `IHttpConnectionFeature` which stores the underlying connection.
4. and so on.

To help store and retrieve a `Type-Instance-Pair`, the interface has three important methods:

```csharp
public interface IFeatureCollection : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, object>>{
    // ...
    object this[Type key] { get; set; }
    TFeature Get<TFeature>();
    void Set<TFeature>(TFeature instance);
}
```

and the implementation (`FeatureCollection`) will simply cast the value into required type:

```csharp
public class FeatureCollection : IFeatureCollection
{
    // ... get the required type of feature
    public TFeature Get<TFeature>()
    {
        return (TFeature)this[typeof(TFeature)];    // note: cast here!
    }

    public void Set<TFeature>(TFeature instance)
    {
        this[typeof(TFeature)] = instance;          // note!
    }
}
```

This is by design. Because there's no need to store two `IHttpConnectionFeature` instances or two `ISession` instances.

While you can store some `Type-Value` pairs with `FeatureCollection`, you'd better not . As you see, the `Set<TFeature>(TFeature instance)` will simply replace the old one if the some type already exists in the collection; it also means there will be a bug if you have two of the same type.

Comment: You said `HttpContext.Items` is short-lived per request, So what is the life-time for a `HttpContext.Features`s member?

Comment: @MohammadBarbast  Well , the exact lifetime is related to the implementation of the `IServer` interface . Actually ,  the `Features` Collection itself and some features like `ServerAddressFeature` are created by the server implemenation even before the `HttpContext`. See  [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/release/2.2/src/Kestrel.Core/KestrelServer.cs#L50)  here .

Answer (score 9):

`HttpContext.Items` is designed to share short-lived per-request data, as you mentioned.

`HttpContext.Features` is designed to share various HTTP features that allow middleware to create or modify the application's hosting pipeline. It's already [filled with several features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/request-features) from .NET, such as `IHttpSendFileFeature`.

You should use `HttpContext.Items` to store data, and `HttpContext.Features` to add any new HTTP features that another middleware class might need.

Comment: So what is the life-time for `HttpContext.Features`?

Comment: @MohammadBarbast it's per-request, same as `HttpContext.Items`. There's a bit more information on this topic in [this GitHub question](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7833).